# Why does Wi-Fi crash when connected to a vpn?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, wifi-configuration, cisco-anyconnect

Here I use [Speed vpn](https://speed-vpn.com/) but it disconnects when the initial WiFi connection is made. I can reconnect it but they may be disconnected after a while. Sometimes it stops when searching some specific websites. I want to know if the cause of this problem is technical or can it be from the government security systems? I know this question is a bit broad so the main question is a way to stabilize the connection when connecting to a vpn. Respond in the comments if more information is needed. Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using WiFi using another device. If the issue persists, it could be the ISP, the VPN, or, as you state, the government blocking sites.

Comment: so can you help me understand why you would connect to WiFi AFTER having connected the VPN? are you on a wired network, and then switching to wifi? Most VPNs either use a virtual network adapter that is connected to your physical network adapter, or modify the existing physical adapters properties, so you can't change your physical connection (wired or wifi) while the VPN is connected, or it will break.